# Code works as a query, produces syntax error with currentdb.execute

Tags: runtime

I have the following code:

`v_sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_eval_general ( id_empleado, id_evaluador, id_tipo_evaluación ) " & _
    "SELECT Empleado_bloques.id_empleado, Empleado_bloques.id_evaluador, Empleado_bloques.id_tipo_evaluación " & _
    " FROM Tipo_evaluación INNER JOIN Empleado_bloques ON Tipo_evaluación.id_tipo_evaluación = Empleado_bloques.id_tipo_evaluación " & _
    " WHERE (((Empleado_bloques.id_empleado)= " & Me.id_empleado & "));"
        CurrentDb.Execute v_sql, dbFailOnError`

This is what v_sql gets:

`INSERT INTO tbl_eval_general ( id_empleado, id_evaluador, id_tipo_evaluación ) 
    SELECT Empleado_bloques.id_empleado, Empleado_bloques.id_evaluador, Empleado_bloques.id_tipo_evaluación

    FROM Tipo_evaluación INNER JOIN Empleado_bloques ON Tipo_evaluación.id_tipo_evaluación = Empleado_bloques.id_tipo_evaluación

    WHERE (((Empleado_bloques.id_empleado)= 125));`

If I copy and paste the resulting code as SQL and create a query, it works. However, when running the code, it works (the record is created) and then I get this error message:

`Run-time error ‘3075:
    Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'INSERT INTO
    tbl_eval_general (id_empleado, id_evaluador, id_tipo_evaluación)
    SELECT Empleado_bloques.id_empleado,
    Empleado_bloques, id_evaluador,
    Empleado_bloques.id_bpo_evaluadón FROM Tipo_evaluación INNER
    JOIN Empleado_bloques ON Tipo_evaluadón.id_bpo_evaluaóón =
    Empleado_bloques.id tipo evaluación WHERE`

It matches the code generated by Access using the query editor. I would appreciate any idea on why a query could work on the editor but not in Currentdb.execute.

Thanks a lot.
Armando.

Comment: I found the error. It was a very dumb mistake. I used the same v_sql variable on a DLOOKUP later in the code. The v_sql had the INSERT code I posted above. DLOOKUP was generating the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. It was a silly mistake. I used the same v_sql variable on a DLOOKUP later in the code. The v_sql had the INSERT code I posted above. DLOOKUP was generating the error message because it was expecting just the condition.